# Transferring Play console data to BigQuery using BigQuery Transfer

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play-console

I am trying to transfer my play store console data to BigQuery using BigQuery transfer service. My play console data is stored in a GCP bucket, which has 3 folders (reviews, stats, acquisition).

While running my BQ transfer job, only the last folder data is getting moved to BigQuery.

Is there any solution to migrate all the three folder data to BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard in your load process can be used like shown in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#load-wildcards)